# Why does this voxel engine crash after a few seconds?

Tags: python, voxels

I'm trying this voxel engine in Python. It runs ok, but it crashes after a few seconds. Does anyone know what is happening?

```
import glfw
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import compileProgram, compileShader
import pyrr
from TextureLoader import load_texture
from random import random as rnd
import numpy as np

from camera import Camera

cam = Camera()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1280, 720
lastX, lastY = WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2
first_mouse = True
left, right, forward, backward = False, False, False, False


# the keyboard input callback
def key_input_clb(window, key, scancode, action, mode):
    global left, right, forward, backward
    if key == glfw.KEY_ESCAPE and action == glfw.PRESS:
        glfw.set_window_should_close(window, True)

    if key == glfw.KEY_W and action == glfw.PRESS:
        forward = True
    elif key == glfw.KEY_W and action == glfw.RELEASE:
        forward = False
    if key == glfw.KEY_S and action == glfw.PRESS:
        backward = True
    elif key == glfw.KEY_S and action == glfw.RELEASE:
        backward = False
    if key == glfw.KEY_A and action == glfw.PRESS:
        left = True
    elif key == glfw.KEY_A and action == glfw.RELEASE:
        left = False
    if key == glfw.KEY_D and action == glfw.PRESS:
        right = True
    elif key == glfw.KEY_D and action == glfw.RELEASE:
        right = False


# do the movement, call this function in the main loop
def do_movement():
    if left:
        cam.process_keyboard("LEFT", 0.05)
    if right:
        cam.process_keyboard("RIGHT", 0.05)
    if forward:
        cam.process_keyboard("FORWARD", 0.05)
    if backward:
        cam.process_keyboard("BACKWARD", 0.05)


# the mouse position callback function
def mouse_look_clb(window, xpos, ypos):
    global first_mouse, lastX, lastY

    if first_mouse:
        lastX = xpos
        lastY = ypos
        first_mouse = False

    xoffset = xpos - lastX
    yoffset = lastY - ypos

    lastX = xpos
    lastY = ypos

    cam.process_mouse_movement(xoffset, yoffset)


vertex_src = """
# version 330
layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 a_texture;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 a_offset;
layout(location = 3) in vec3 a_offset_texture;//In order for every cube to have it's own texture
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 move;
out vec2 v_texture;
void main()
{
    vec3 final_pos=vec3(0.,0.,0.);//= a_position + a_offset;
    final_pos.x = a_position.x + a_offset.x;
    final_pos.y = a_position.y + a_offset.y;
    final_pos.z = a_position.z + a_offset.z;
    gl_Position =  projection * view * move * vec4(final_pos,1.);
    v_texture.xy = a_texture.xy + a_offset_texture.xy;
    //v_texture = a_texture + a_offset_texture; code here
}
"""

fragment_src = """
# version 330
in vec2 v_texture;
out vec4 out_color;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;

float map(float value, float min1, float max1, float min2, float max2) {
  return min2 + (value - min1) * (max2 - min2) / (max1 - min1);
}

float roundValues(float fvalue,float ivalue) {
    return 0.f;
}

void main()
{
    vec3 sky_col = vec3(172./256.,32./256.,32./256.);
    
    vec4 in_col = texture(s_texture, v_texture);
    
    float coe = 1.-gl_FragCoord.z/(100.*gl_FragCoord.w);
    
    in_col.x = map(coe,0.,1.,sky_col.x,in_col.x);
    in_col.y = map(coe,0.,1.,sky_col.y,in_col.y);
    in_col.z = map(coe,0.,1.,sky_col.z,in_col.z);
    
    out_color = in_col;
}
"""


# the window resize callback function
def window_resize_clb(window, width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    projection = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(45, width / height, 0.1, 100)
    glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection)


# initializing glfw library
if not glfw.init():
    raise Exception("glfw can not be initialized!")

# creating the window
window = glfw.create_window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "My OpenGL window", None, None)

# check if window was created
if not window:
    glfw.terminate()
    raise Exception("glfw window can not be created!")

# set window's position
glfw.set_window_pos(window, 400, 200)

# set the callback function for window resize
glfw.set_window_size_callback(window, window_resize_clb)
# set the mouse position callback
glfw.set_cursor_pos_callback(window, mouse_look_clb)
# set the keyboard input callback
glfw.set_key_callback(window, key_input_clb)
# capture the mouse cursor
glfw.set_input_mode(window, glfw.CURSOR, glfw.CURSOR_DISABLED)

# make the context current
glfw.make_context_current(window)

multiplier=float(2.)
batch_coe=float(1./multiplier)

#              positions        texture_coords
cube_buffer = [-0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0.0, 0.0,#where it used to be 1.as image uperbounds, now it hase been replaced with batch_coe
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, batch_coe, 0.0,
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, batch_coe, batch_coe,
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0.0, batch_coe,

            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, batch_coe, 0.0,
             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, batch_coe, batch_coe,
            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0.0, batch_coe,

             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, batch_coe, 0.0,
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, batch_coe, batch_coe,
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0.0, batch_coe,

            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, batch_coe, 0.0,
            -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, batch_coe, batch_coe,
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0.0, batch_coe,

            -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5, -0.5, batch_coe, 0.0,
             0.5, -0.5,  0.5, batch_coe, batch_coe,
            -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, 0.0, batch_coe,

             0.5,  0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
            -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, batch_coe, 0.0,
            -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, batch_coe, batch_coe,
             0.5,  0.5,  0.5, 0.0, batch_coe]

cube_buffer = np.array(cube_buffer, dtype=np.float32)

cube_indices = [ 0,  1,  2,  2,  3,  0,
                 6,  5,  4,  4,  7,  6,#it needs fixing in indexing and invericies
                 8,  9, 10, 10, 11,  8,
                12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 12,
                16, 17, 18, 18, 19, 16,
                20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 20]
                #4,  5,  6,  6,  7,  4

cube_indices = np.array(cube_indices, dtype=np.uint32)

shader = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER), compileShader(fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

# VAO, VBO and EBO
VAO = glGenVertexArrays(1)
VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
EBO = glGenBuffers(1)

# cube VAO
glBindVertexArray(VAO)
# cube Vertex Buffer Object
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_buffer.nbytes, cube_buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
# cube Element Buffer Object
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_indices.nbytes, cube_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

# cube vertices
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, cube_buffer.itemsize * 5, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
# cube textures
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, cube_buffer.itemsize * 5, ctypes.c_void_p(12))

textures = glGenTextures(1)
load_texture("basilikh_kakava.jpg", textures)

#### instance VBO
instance_array = []
offset = 1

for z in range(0, 50, 2):
    for y in range(0, 50, 2):
        for x in range(0, 50, 2):
            translation = pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
            translation.x = x + offset
            translation.y = y + offset
            translation.z = z + offset
            instance_array.append(translation)

len_of_instance_array = len(instance_array) # do this before you flatten the array
instance_array = np.array(instance_array, np.float32).flatten()
####
#### instance VBO texture
instance_array_text = []

for z in range(0, 50, 2):
    for y in range(0, 50, 2):
        for x in range(0, 50, 2):
            translation = pyrr.Vector3([0.0, 0.0,0.0])
            instance_array_text.append(translation)

len_of_instance_array_text = len(instance_array_text) # do this before you flatten the array
instance_array_text = np.array(instance_array, np.float32).flatten()
####

instanceVBO = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instance_array.nbytes, instanceVBO, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
#glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instance_array.nbytes, instance_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1) # 1 means, every instance will have it's own translate

####new code for textures

#instanceVBO_text = glGenBuffers(1)
#glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO_text)
#glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instance_array_text.nbytes, None, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)

#glEnableVertexAttribArray(3)
#glVertexAttribPointer(3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
#glVertexAttribDivisor(3, 1) # 1 means, every instance will have it's own texture

####

glUseProgram(shader)
glClearColor(172./256.,32./256.,32./256.,1.)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

projection = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 100)
cube_pos = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(pyrr.Vector3([0., 0., 0.]))

#model_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "model")
proj_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "projection")
view_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view")
move_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "move")

glUniformMatrix4fv(proj_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection)
#glUniformMatrix4fv(model_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, cube_pos)

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);

# the main application loop
while not glfw.window_should_close(window):
    
    #index=int(rnd()*(len_of_instance_array_text-1)*3)
    
    #instance_array[index]=rnd()*100
    
    #instance_array_text[index]=batch_coe*int(rnd()*multiplier)
    print("0")
    #glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO)
    #glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0, instance_array.nbytes, instance_array)
    
    print("1")
    #glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO_text)
    #glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0, instance_array_text.nbytes, instance_array_text)
    print("2")
    glfw.poll_events()
    do_movement()
    print("3")
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    print("4")
    move = pyrr.matrix44.create_from_translation(pyrr.Vector3([0., 0., 0.]))
    print("5")
    glUniformMatrix4fv(move_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, move)
    print("6")
    view = cam.get_view_matrix()
    glUniformMatrix4fv(view_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, view)
    print("7")
    glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, len(cube_indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None, len_of_instance_array)
    print("8")
    glfw.swap_buffers(window)
    print("9")
# terminate glfw, free up allocated resources
glfw.terminate()
```

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you taken? Do you get any particular error message on crash? Have you run this with a debugger that can give you information about where the crash originated? Have you tried instrumenting the code with logs so you can determine the last section executed or the last game state prior to the crash? Most volunteers won't do those steps on your behalf, so it helps to do as much legwork as you can to narrow down the cause of the issue. Ideally, you'd shrink this question from a complete dump of all the code to just a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.

Comment: what does the message say when it crashes?